# Can't edit the css to make the background only on a specific page go black

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to get the white border on this page to disappear:

http://www.donaldrussell.com/blog/carving
password:testpage

I only want it to disappear on pages with this specific template.

Here's the CSS I'm trying to use:

```
.fullwidth #wrapper{

background-color:#000;}
```

Can anyone point out what's wrong please?

Thanks

It's the white border, I would like to get rid of, so it looks like this:
 [image: How I want it to look]

Comment: You mean the white border around the top part of the website?

Comment: yes - sorry no to make that clearer.

Comment: Maybe post a screenshot of your desired result?

Comment: `#wrapper` is a parent of `.fullwidth` so the CSS you've posted should have no effect. But you have a handful of classes on the `body` element you could use to narrow the effect of your CSS rule, for example `.page-id-7703 #wrapper { background:#000; }` for this single page only.

Comment: Thanks Pawel, this works, But I have to add it for all 3 pages I want it to happen on - but that's OK

Comment: @PeterKirkwood if these three pages (and olny these) share the `.page-template-onecolumn-sliderpage-php` class name use it instead of `.page-id-xxx`

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure where the `.fullwidth` class is actually being used on the page.

The white background is being called from the main `style.css` stylesheet on line `224`.

If you have access to that file, then just change the value there.

If not, try adding this to the page.

```
#wrapper.black_bg{
    background-color:#000 !important;
}
```

and change your wrapper div to this:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="hfeed black_bg">
```

Comment: This will modify the wrapper for all pages.  Seeing as I doubt he imports a new CSS stylesheet per page, as that doesn't make sense.

Comment: from what ive read in the question and how the site is setup, i would guess that he wants the background set to black across all the pages.

Comment: His title says "on;ly on a specific page go black" but yeah his question kind of leans that way.  I see the confusion, he isn't 100% clear.

Comment: @SimplyCraig "I only want it to disappear on pages with this specific template."

Comment: Yeah considering what he is asking is .fullwidth #wrapper, and that isn't even part of his page.  Looks fine to me.

Comment: There is a `fullwidth` element now ive looked further down the stack, problem is that it effects nothing to do with the background he wants to remove

Answer (score 1):

There is no parent container with the class .fullwidth (as far as I can see). The only option for classes in your body (which is the parent container in this case) are:

```
<body class="page page-id-7703 page-template page-template-onecolumn-sliderpage-php custom-background">
```

Try instead adding a class to the wrapper and styling this:

```
.page-template-onecolumn-sliderpage-php .SOME-CLASS{

    background-color:#000;

}
```

You shouldn't use the class then ID like that. best to stick to classes when styling.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want it to disappear only on on the pages with that particular template, here's what you do.

1. Open the page's template and add an ID called "login-page" to the body tag so that you can target it separately.
2. Then create the block of CSS code below being specific with the ID you added to the template's body tag.

   #login-page #wrapper {

   background-color: #000; /* or Inherit */

   }

**Note** You can change or add to the above block of code and it'll affect just the the template that you applied the the given ID to.